# Generate random HH:MM:SS using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

How can I generate a random `HH:MM:SS` time using `datetime`?

I get just `00:00:00` everytime

```
import datetime

print(datetime.time())
>>> 00:00:00
```

Comment: `import random` `datetime.time(hour=random.randint(0, 23), ...)`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest answer I could think of. Thanks @deceze for inspiration.

```py
import datetime
import random

print(datetime.time(hour=random.randint(0, 23), minute=random.randint(0, 59), second=random.randint(0, 59)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

min_year=1900
max_year=datetime.now().year

start = datetime(min_year, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00)
years = max_year - min_year+1
end = start + timedelta(days=365 * years)

for i in range(10):
random_date = start + (end - start) * random.random()
print(random_date)

#done

# or a function
def gen_datetime(min_year=1900, max_year=datetime.now().year):
# generate a datetime in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000000
start = datetime(min_year, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00)
years = max_year - min_year + 1
end = start + timedelta(days=365 * years)
return start + (end - start) * random.random()
```

from https://gist.github.com/rg3915/db907d7455a4949dbe69